# How can I communicate custom task and another class in rxJava2?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I create a task in class (A) and call asynchronously then if the task is finished or canceled pass the result another class(B) with using in rxJava2 .I am very new in rxJava2 and I confused.What can I use this logic?
Completable or Flowable?

What I want to do

call asynchronously task class (B)
run task and emit some result class(A)
then subscribe the task result in class(B)
Any idea ? Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have some task A and B exposed as streams, ex. `Single<TaskAResult>` and `Single<TaskBResult>`.
Use flatMap to subscribe to task B after task A emits result.

```
taskA.flatMap(taskAResult -> taskB(taskAResult))
        .subscribe(taskBResult -> {
            // do whatever after task B finishes
        });
```

And you have a method `Single<TaskBResult> taskB(TaskAResult result)` which will create Task B based on Task A result.

Comment: Thanks for answer but my tasks running concurency automatically and I wait this tasks repsonses another task.Can I use all tasks flatMap?

Comment: Yes you can chain multiple tasks, tell more I'll try to help

Comment: First of all I did not found asynchronous l method call in rxJava2.I call this methods and this method call another with response.

Comment: You make operations asynchronous if you let RxJava stream operate on a particular Scheduler, ex. `Schedulers.io()` using `observeOn()`/`subscribeOn()`

Comment: Okay I understand Scheduler but I dont understand how can I use this,for ex method A how can I call and run asynchronously? Like this       Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return loadInBackground();
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
});

Comment: Yes exactly, and loadInBackground will be called on new thread. And you will get result on android main thread